# How to return index after groupby condition it meet?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large df.pandas and I wanted to make a function to groupby a column and count uniqe values in another column and then return the index of the max count value, like so:

```
def groupby_fun():
    x = df.groupby(by=df['Column1'])['Column2'].nunique()
    return [x.max()].index[0]
groupby_fun()
```

I get this error:

```
'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

what am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: What's with the square brackets around x.max()?

Comment: Plus it should be index(), not square brackets

Comment: That's not the issue thought

Comment: I changed it to return x.max.index(), same error but rephrased: 'function' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: Also i use index[0] to get the string value otherwise I get : Index(['string'], dtype='object')

Comment: `df.groupby('Column1')['Column2'].nunique().idxmax()`. Aside - `max` returns a scalar value and not a series object and so you cannot access the index via that.

Comment: that worked .idxmax()

Answer (score 1):

Adding `.idxmax()` as Nickil Maveli suggested worked:

```
df.groupby('Column1')['Column2'].nunique().idxmax()
```